# Remove QA attributes from Angular production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Base on [this article](https://www.utest.com/articles/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation) I would like to use `data-qa` attributes but I don't think that is a good approach to leave them in a production build. Do you know any way to remove them from an Angular production build, with (or without) Angular CLI?

Comment: I think you may do a script to remove it by yourself. It is just a regex? I am interested.

Comment: Duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794288/when-developing-e2e-tests-why-is-data-attributes-preferred-for-element-select I think. But there are some suggestions in the duplicated answer.